# Capture images in python using the camera on my laptop (color or gray scale)

Tags: machine-learning, networking, artificial-intelligence

For my mac, I want to use Python to capture images, then convert them to numpy arrays (both color or gray scale will work for me). Even storing the images to disk first and then converting them later through a script is fine as well.

I have read that cv2 can be useful, which I have tried and failed to setup or use it. Any help including a code sample is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture an Image using OpenCV using the following code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-capture-video-from-camera/:

```py
# import the opencv library
import cv2
  
  
# define a video capture object
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  
while(True):
      
    # Capture the video frame
    # by frame
    ret, frame = vid.read()

    # convert to grayscale
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
      
    # the 'q' button is set as the
    # quitting button you may use any
    # desired button of your choice
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
  
# After the loop release the cap object
vid.release()
# Destroy all the windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```